# Content-Disposition is always null in web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very simple form:

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="~/Api/File/Post" method="post" >
    <input type="file" name="files[0].media" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When debugging I get the file, but `fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition` is always null so I can not access the file name. I dont see any other property in the Request object to get the file name.

What confuses me the most is inspecting the request with chromes debugger shows the following details

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary3rLRRBQX6jj7MbWU
------WebKitFormBoundary3rLRRBQX6jj7MbWU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0].media"; filename="MyFileName.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundary3rLRRBQX6jj7MbWU--
```

Any ideas? This looks like it is being sent correctly... (removed file name in example above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the html form provided in your question you should be able to access the file data using the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var filesProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    var fileContents = filesProvider.Contents.FirstOrDefault();
    if (fileContents == null)
    {
        return this.BadRequest("Missing file");
    }

    var headers = fileContents.Headers;
    string filename = headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
    Stream fileStream = await fileContents.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    ... do something with the file name and stream
}
```

Comment: Solution was to do it for each file after var filesProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync()! Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!
Web Api 2.2, Visual Studio 2015 and IIS 10